# What are the foundations to learn before learning path-finding algorithm like BFS, DFS etc?

Tags: java, data-structures

I am trying to understand about BFS/DFS implementation in programming, and it doesn't make much sense to me. 
Like how a 2d array is related to a Graph, so I'd like to know what foundations am I missing, that makes me really hard to understand the implementation in programming, in my case it's java.
Will be much appreciated too if someone can lists the sources recommendation to learn the foundations I need.

Comment: Resource requests like this are off-topic. You're better searching google or amazon's recommendations.

Comment: I would say Algorithms, 4th Edition by Robert Sedgewick https://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/home/ is  a good start

Comment: "how a 2d array is related to a Graph" google *representing graph as array* or something similar and you should find many articles like https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/graph-and-its-representations/

Comment: Im not necessarily requesting for resource, its advice and suggestion that i need, because i cant find those when i googled @Flimzy

Comment: Your question says "lists the sources recommendation" This is exactly what is off-topic.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I strongly recommend you watch [freeCodeCamp - Graph Theory video](https://youtu.be/09_LlHjoEiY), as a Computer Science student that video had a lot of information that were hard to get/understand in my college course, even though BFS and DFS aren't that hard yet still important to know them along with other Graph Algorithms